# How to query objects with a one-to-one relationship

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    m1 = models.OneToOneField(Model1, related_name='m2')
    ...
```

I want to get queryset of Model1 objects that have a Model2 defined.  Something like this:

```
objs = Model1.objects.filter('m2'!=None)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
objs = Model1.objects.filter('m2'!=None)
```

The argument in the brackets will be evaluated. What you're asking of the ORM is, therefore:

```
objs = Model1.objects.filter(False)
```

What you meant was:

```
objs = Model1.objects.filter(m2__isnull=False)
```

- Link: [`isnull` in the Django QuerySet API Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-isnull)